# Authentication errors with Cloud Dataproc and other Google Cloud products

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to use [Google Cloud PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub) with my [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) cluster and I am getting authentication scope errors like the following:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

How can I resolve this issue so I can use PubSub (and other Google Cloud) products in my Spark/Hadoop projects running on Cloud Dataproc?

Answer (score 4):

Google Cloud Dataproc includes some [authentication scopes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication?hl=en#oauth-scopes) by default but does not presently include scopes for all Google Cloud Platform products. You can add scopes to a cluster by creating them with the [Google Cloud SDK](http://cloud.google.com/sdk) and using the `--scopes` flag.

For example, you can use the following flag when using the `gcloud beta dataproc clusters create` command to add the PubSub scope `--scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub`. As long as the service handles the "catch all" scope, you can use `--scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` to add scopes for many services at once.

You can find more information about authentication and authorization on the [Google Cloud Platform docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#oauth_scopes).

Comment: can we add or update scopes later after dataproc cluster was created